# How to form a TypeScript rule/config that errors if I don't return a JSX in React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've made the mistake multiple times where I forget to return a JSX from a functional component.  That is, I do something like the following:

```
const Hello = function Hello({name}) {
  <div>Hello  {name}</div>
}
```

Instead of

```
const Hello = function Hello({name}) {
  return <div>Hello  {name}</div>
}
```

I totally know why it's wrong, but I often conflate the the ES6 syntax that does not need a return mentioned with this.

Is there any help TypeScript can give me so I see it as an error before I run it and get the error saying a return is likely missing?

Here is a stackblitz of the problem:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-badreturn?file=Hello.tsx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options. The best one is to annotate the constant with `React.FunctionComponent<P>` type.

```
import * as React from 'react';

const Hello: React.FunctionComponent<{ name: string }> = function Hello({name}) { // error  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'
    <div>Hello  {name}</div> 
}
```

Another option is to just specify the return type of the function

```
import * as React from 'react';

const Hello = function Hello({name}) : React.ReactElement<any> { // error  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'
    <div>Hello  {name}</div> 
}
// arrow function 
const Hello = ({name}) : React.ReactElement<any> => { // error  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'
    <div>Hello  {name}</div> 
}
```

**Note** Even without any of these annotations typescript will still help, it will report an error if you try to use the mistaken version of `Hello` in tsx.

**Edit**

Another option is to use tslint with the `no-unused-expression` rule turned on. This rule will ensure that:

> Unused expressions are expression statements which are not assignments or function calls (and thus usually no-ops).

This will cover the case when you create a jsx element and do nothing with it.

Comment: I'm wondering if TSLint will catch this if you enable "noUnusedVariable" flag. https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-variable/ My thoughts are that the JSX will be unused local variables.

Comment: @cgTag Don't think so. There is no variable, just an unused expression so tslint should have no reason to complain.

Comment: @cgTag perhaps `no-unused-expression`

Comment: @cgTag yo were right about using tslint as a good option, added it, the `no-unused-expression` reports an error as expected

Comment: Cool. I was just making a guess :)

Comment: Cuties what the import * as does?

Comment: Meant “curious” what does import * as mean

Answer (score 0):

Add type checking for props.

```
import React from 'react';

const Hello = function Hello(props: {name: string}) {
  <div>Hello  {props.name}</div>
}

export default Hello;
```

you will get following error

```
Error in 0.8.16/lib/invariant.js (42:15)
Hello(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```